# JDK 11 Spring Boot 2 .TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.servlet.Filter not present

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, openjdk-11

I have the following pom.xml with included manually jax deps `jaxb-api`, `jaxb-impl` and `jaxb-core` due to its removal from JDK 11:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.M2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--TEST-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--Three below dependencies due to JDK 11 removed jaxb-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--For Eureka Client-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Cloud Config Client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!--To provide version for Eureka Client -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>

        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

After `mvn clean:install` however when trying to run app I keep getting this error about filter.

> 22:45:16.622 [main] DEBUG
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -
>   Creating shared instance of singleton bean
>   'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshAutoConfiguration$RefreshScopeBeanDefinitionEnhancer'
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type
>   javax.servlet.Filter not present  at
>   java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.computeSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:117)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:95)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:1138)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.getInterfaces(ResolvableType.java:491)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.as(ResolvableType.java:449)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.as(ResolvableType.java:450)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1305)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1272)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1262)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.BridgeMethodResolver.isResolvedTypeMatch(BridgeMethodResolver.java:157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.BridgeMethodResolver.isBridgeMethodFor(BridgeMethodResolver.java:141)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.BridgeMethodResolver.searchCandidates(BridgeMethodResolver.java:120)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.BridgeMethodResolver.findBridgedMethod(BridgeMethodResolver.java:82)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.processMethodAnnotations(AnnotationsScanner.java:386)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.processMethodHierarchy(AnnotationsScanner.java:266)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.processMethod(AnnotationsScanner.java:236)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.process(AnnotationsScanner.java:109)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.scan(AnnotationsScanner.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationsScanner.scan(AnnotationsScanner.java:77)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotations.scan(TypeMappedAnnotations.java:241)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotations.isPresent(TypeMappedAnnotations.java:97)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.hasAnnotation(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:531)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.BeanAnnotationHelper.isBeanAnnotated(BeanAnnotationHelper.java:41)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.isMatch(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:439)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$ConditionalCallbackFilter.accept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:192)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.emitMethods(Enhancer.java:1214)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:723)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanFactoryAwareGeneratorStrategy.generate(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:252)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:358)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:582)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
>     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:134)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:319)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:569)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:416)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:137)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:109)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:429)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:263)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:286)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:130)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:88)
>     at
>   com.example.authservice.AuthServiceApplication.main(AuthServiceApplication.java:13)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)    at
>   java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)     at
>   java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)

What else is wrong after adding the 3 additional deps?

Comment: Same pom works on my machine (JDK 11.0.2) and `mvn clean install` passes.


Btw. `javax.servlet.Filter` is a part of tomcat libs and, because you have webflux starter, you use netty. `WebFilter` should be used instead `Filter`. More: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/WebFilter.html

Comment: @Adam Bukowiecki It fails at app start not at maven clean install ;) How can I check what requires this `Filter` ?

Comment: Ah, sorry, my mistake :) Anyway it starts too (app only, with no Eureka server) on my machine so debuging is quite hard. 

What can make investigation easier I think is a breakpoint in `CoreReflectionFactory` line 117 (`throw new TypeNotPresentException(name, c);`), then you could have a look at the frames and figure out what class implements `Filter` (or interface which extends `Filter`).

Answer (score 0):

The spring-security-oauth2 project currently has a hard dependency on Spring MVC and the Servlet API. Please refer to [WebFlux oauth2 doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/webflux-oauth2.html)